# Benefit of Ephemeral Ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I know what ephemeral ports are. They are just assigned dynamically by the server. But what is the benefit of using ephemeral ports? Does it help with security or performance or something else? And How? For example, if my incoming http traffic is on port 80 and I assign ephemeral port to the outgoing http traffic. What would we achieve in this case?

Comment: Security through obscurity, nothing else

Comment: [Simplifying Ephemeral Ports with Example - Whizlabs Blog](https://www.whizlabs.com/blog/ephemeral-ports/)